# Calculator distance between two points after move x steps

Tags: javascript

I have **static** destination point `(x2, y2)`, and **dynamic** point `(x1, y1)` that need reach the destination.

Every round I get x steps that the **dynamic** point make, and I need to calculate the new dynamic point `(x1, y1)` after the x steps it make .

I have the distance between the two point:

```
const distance = Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
```

But need to calculate the new `(x1, y1)` after the steps towards the destination, how can I get it done via this formula?

**For example:**

point1 = (x1, y1) = (100, 100)

point2 = (x2, y2) = (400, 400)

distance = ~424

Now the **point1** move "30" steps in a straight line to the **point2** direction, meaning that the distance is now `(distance - 30)` I think?, what is the new (x1, y1) ?

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, now add it

Comment: Calculate the direction and the new position. The `direction` is `[x2, y2] - [x1, y1]`. The `unitVector` in this direction is `direction / |direction|`. The new position is `[x1, y1] + 30 * unitVector`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but cant understand from this comment what you mean by `[x1, y1] + 30` and `[x2, y2] - [x1, y1]`

Comment: In your example the unit vector is `[1, 1] / sqrt(2) = [0.707..., 0.707...]`. The new position is `[121.213..., 121.213...]`. You can calculate the new distance. It's `~394`.

Comment: We are talking about vectors. `unitVector`, `[x2, y2]`, `[x1, y1]` and `[x2, y2] - [x1, y1]` are vectors. You used parenthesis and I used brackets. `30 * unitVector` is a vector. `[x1, y1] + 30 * unitVector` is also a vector.

Comment: you cannot calculate like that, the new (x1, y1) can be any point in a circumference

Comment: @syduki _"Now the point1 move "30" steps in a straight line to the point2 direction"_ You have to calculate it this way. The new position is unambiguous.

Comment: yes, I got this, I just read it too superficial for the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algorithm as mathematical pseudo code:

1. Calculate the direction: `direction = (x2, y2) - (x1, y1)`
2. Calculate the unit vector for this direction: `unitVector = direction / |direction|`
3. Add the steps in direction to the old position: `newPos = (x1, y1) + steps * unitVector`

In your example you get:

1. `(300, 300)`
2. `(0.707..., 0.707...)`
3. `30 * (0.707..., 0.707...) + (100, 100) = (121.213..., 121.213...)`

The new distance is `~394 = ~424 - 30` with rounding error.

Comment: this `unitVector = direction / |direction|` not always be 1 ?

Comment: @BallonUra The length of a [unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) is always 1.

Answer (score 1):

you can get xN, yN like this [Partitioning a Segment in a Given Ratio](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/partioning-a-segment-in-a-given-ratio):

```js
const [x1, y1] = [100, 100];
const [x2, y2] = [400, 400];
const distance = Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
const delta = 30;
const coef = delta / distance;

const calc = (p1, p2) => coef * (p2 - p1) + p1;

const x3 = calc(x1, x2);
const y3 = calc(y1, y2);

console.log(x3, y3);
```

Comment: [What comment should I add to code-only answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers) Please don't answer a beginner's question with a code-only answer.

Comment: Why `const calc = (p1, p2) => coef * (p2 - p1) + p1` you add p1 at the end ? what about the p2?

Comment: yeah, I've probably should have added some info, updated

Comment: @Thomas Sablik i tried but did't found the definition of "beginner" on this site, moreover I'm a little confused since I cannot understand, is the OP being a member since "6 years, 2 months" is more beginner than me with only "7 months", or are you less beginner with "6 years"? Or there are other qualifications for this term? Can you please explain?

Comment: A beginner is someone who doesn't know the basics of a topic, e.g. geometry. [dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/beginner) _"a person who has begun a course of instruction or is learning the fundamentals"_ Calculating the direction and unit vector is usually taught at the very beginning of each geometry course. Please post the explanation into your answer. Links can invalidate.